# Log out all sessions of Google brand account

Tags: gmail, google-account, google-brand-account

In Gmail, I’ve “logged out all sessions”. Will this also log out all sessions of brand accounts?

Comment: What do you mean by “brand accounts”?

Comment: @Alex There some services like Google Photos and Youtube that support this kind of accounts. They could be managed by several users by using their own Google Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Google Brand Accounts are accessed through a Google Account- By logging out of your account will not log out other users from their accounts, and will not block them to access the Brand Account.

If you are the owner of the Brand Account you could add/remove other accounts to help manage it.

NOTE:

There is no login/logout for Brand Accounts only for the Google Accounts that could be used to manage a Brand Account. If you log out of your Google Account then no others could use iT to access your Brand Account.

References

- [Manage your Brand Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7001996?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
- [Change who manages your Brand Account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/7311601?hl=en&ref_topic=7188671)

Comment: They only have access to the. brand account, right?  They can't access my gmail, can they?  I'm confused, because the password for my gmail is the same password as the brand account.

Comment: @Bubba That's right, they can't access your Gmail's mailbox.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  How about if I use my brand accoint on someone elses computer, but forget to sign out.  If I log into gmail from my computer and 'log out all sessions',would that log out the brand account on that other computer?

Comment: There is no login/logout for Brand Accounts only for the Google Accounts that could be used to manage a Brand Account. If you log out of your Google Account then no others could use it to access your Brand Account.